# App Engine return JSON from JsonProperty

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I like how the `JsonProperty` automatically encodes a Python structure into JSON when the property is put into the data store, and automatically decodes it when retrieved.  However, it would be nice to send that JSON data to a web browser without having to encode it again.  Is there a way to get the raw JSON data (that is, prevent the decoding)?

```
class DataForBrowser(ndb.Models)
    json = ndb.JsonProperty()

    def get_json(self):
        return ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you want is to have a dict that gets encoded when saved to the datastore but not decoded upon retrieving it... What happens "under the hood" is that a JsonProperty is a subclass of BlobProperty that gets encoded (json.dumps()) every time it gets written to the datastore and decoded (json.loads()) every time it's read. 
This can be done only with a [property subclass](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop) that eliminates one of these functions (but I don't think it's wise to have different behaviors for the property according to the state the entity is). Just for "educational purposes" let's see what will happen then

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import json

class ExtendedJsonProperty(ndb.BlobProperty):
  def _to_base_type(self, value):
    return json.dumps(value) 

  def _from_base_type(self, value):
    return value
    # originally return json.loads(value)

class DataForBrowser(ndb.Model):
    json = ExtendedJsonProperty()


data = {'a': 'A'}
data_for_browser = DataForBrowser()
data_for_browser.json = data
print type(data_for_browser.json)  # returns <type 'dict'>
data_for_browser.put()
print type(data_for_browser.json) # returns <type 'str'>
data_for_browser_retrieverd = DataForBrowser.query().get()
print type(data_for_browser_retrieverd.json) # returns <type 'str'>
```

If you need to make use of the dict in your code then I suggest using a **JsonProperty** and adding a new property method that will return the dict as JSON and use that.

```
@property
def json_as_json(self):
  return json.dumps(self.json)
```

If you use the dict only to create the JSON data then just use a **BlobProperty** and pass through **json.dumps()** before assigning the data to the property

Comment: Yes, that's similar to what I'm currently doing now.  I'm wondering if there is a "back door" method (like a Hook method) that will simply return the JSON string from a `JsonProperty`.  It seems like going backwards to introduce the `ExtendedJsonProperty`.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible since the _from_base_type() method is called right after the data is fetched from the datastore. From that point on, the original data isn't accessible anymore.

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted, but I think it's the correct answer.